# React Redux App в Opera показывает пустой экран

Tags: reactjs, redux, create-react-app, opera

Создал новое React Redux приложение по документации командой npx degit reduxjs/redux-templates/packages/vite-template-redux my-app. Но при первом запуске в браузере Opera пустой экран, ошибок в консоле нет. Если я начинаю менять файлы, в консоле появляются ошибки, то есть он их видит но создает пустую страницу. В Chrome все работает. Подскажите в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Что за ошибки то?

Comment: Когда я начинаю ломать проект приложение это видит и выдает ошибки, когда все нормально делает просто пустой body

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. Проблема оказалась в блокировщике рекламы, блокировал некоторые компоненты